# Excel vba combobox.value reads 10 times the decimal value

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

In vba, i read value from combobox but for decimal values it gets the 10 times of amount. It works fine for integers and it works on other peoples computers, im guessing something is wrong in my settings. Does anyone know how can i fix?

Here is the related code parts:

```
Dim Rt, r As Double
ComboBox3.RowSource = "Datas! B2:B11"
r = ComboBox3.Value
MsgBox ("r is equal to" & r)
```

[value and value read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBlyp.png)

getting value from these cells, cell format is number. "dot" is decimal seperator.
[cells image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H9NJ.png)

Comment: What is decimal separator, according to your local settings? Is it comma? Please, show us how exactly the `ComboBox3.Value` looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combobox returns text values, so convert with *Val* which always reads dot as the decimal separator:

```
r = Val(ComboBox3.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use these two functions to deal with the problem like the one you present. `NumberValue` returns a number of Double type extracted from a string as you might have in a form control like text or combo box. This function will try and determine if the number uses a decimal point or comma but it also takes an argument to define the system using this enumeration.

```
Enum Ndp                            ' Decimal point
    ' NIC 003 14 Sep 2020
    NdpEN = 1                       ' decimal point
    NdpDE                           ' decimal comma
End Enum
```

`NumberText` works the opposite way but only has the capability to return numbers with a decimal point, and the comma as thousands separator. That would be very easy to flip if you need your combo box to display German number formats.

```
Function NumberText(ByVal Number As Variant, _
                    Optional ByVal Decs As Integer, _
                    Optional Suffix As String) As String
    ' NIC 003 13 Sep 2020
    'returns an Absolute number
    
    Dim Mask    As String
    
    Mask = "#,##0"
    If Decs Then Mask = Mask & Left(".000000", Decs + 1)
    NumberText = Format(Abs(CDbl(Number)), Mask) & Suffix
End Function

Function NumberValue(ByVal Number As Variant, _
                     Optional ByVal Dp As Ndp) As Double
    ' Nic 003 14 Sep 2020
    ' dp defines the separators used in Number
    ' return Number with decimal point regardless of input
    ' removes any thousands separator
    ' in numbers with 3 decimals the separator is deemed a
    ' thousands separator if Dp isn't supplied.
    
    Dim Fun     As String
    Dim Char    As String
    Dim Sp()    As String
    Dim n       As Integer
    Dim p       As Integer
    
    If IsNumeric(Number) Then
        Fun = CStr(Number)
    Else
        For n = 1 To Len(Number)
            Char = Mid(Number, n, 1)
            If InStr("01234567890.,", Char) Then Fun = Fun & Char
        Next n
    End If
    Number = Fun
    
    If Len(Number) Then
        If Dp = 0 Then
            p = InStr(Number, ".")
            n = InStr(Number, ",")
            If p Then
                ' Number contains a period
                If n Then
                    ' both separators are present
                    Dp = IIf(n < p, NdpEN, NdpDE)
                Else
                    ' only period is present
                    Sp = Split(Number, ".")
                    Dp = IIf(Len(Sp(UBound(Sp))) = 3, NdpDE, NdpEN)
               End If
            Else
                ' Number contains no period
                If n Then
                    Sp = Split(Number, ",")
                    ' only comma is present
                    Dp = IIf(Len(Sp(UBound(Sp))) = 3, NdpEN, NdpDE)
                Else
                    Dp = NdpEN
                End If
            End If
        End If
    
        If Dp = NdpEN Then
            NumberValue = WorksheetFunction.NumberValue(Fun, ".", ",")
        Else
            NumberValue = WorksheetFunction.NumberValue(Fun, ",", ".")
        End If
    Else
        NumberValue = Val(Fun)
    End If
End Function
```

Another idea that might be useful to you: I store the actual number in the control's `Tag` property for use within the form. So ...

```
' On Change or AfterUpdate: 
    Control.Tag = NumberValue(Control.Value)
    Control.Value = NumberText(Control.Tag, 2) - [*Suffix* is a string like unit or measure or +/-*]

' But retrieve the value with 
    Val(Control.Tag]
```